# Add an option to 'promote comment to answer'

Tags: feature-request, answers, comments

All too often I get a great answer posted as a comment. No idea why the response wasn't entered as an answer but it's usually followed by

> post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

How tough would it be to add a button to do this auto-magically? Either for the OP or the commenter.

Comment: Why not just expand on the comment in your own answer and accept it?

Comment: This has previously been requested on [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question) and was declined.  If you find that a comment solves your problem, why not ask the user to post it as an answer or answer the question yourself?

Comment: For a while, I always wondered why we don't have that feature, but then I stumbled over a question where the comment was posted as an answer (after a request), and downvoted into oblivion. Nothing I would ever want as someone who posts a comment.

Comment: I often do that because I'm not 100% sure that I've got the correct diagnosis for some bug.  If I put in answer and it's incorrect, I get downvotes:(

Comment: @bluefeet both of your options are suboptimal because of process friction: they both require additional effort that exceeds the value of the action. They depend on delayed action: commenters may not return for several days or ever, and (especially for new users who are still figuring out what is appropriate) first, it can seem odd to answer your own question (with someone else’s words) and second, because of the system enforced delay, marking it ‘correct’ relies on the user returning later to do this. So many of these ‘answered’ questions remain marked as ‘unanswered’.

Comment: Promoting the comment to an answer isn't really the issue here though. The real problem is that for a variety of reasons it may not be appropriate to promote a comment to an answer (see the answers below) but the question should still be marked as correctly answered so that people looking for the solution know it may be there, and so those planning to answer the question don't waste time going in to find it already answered.

Comment: @bluefeet that's like saying that a trek over a mountain to a valley on the other side of the mountain is a suboptimal solution because there is no path that traverses a flat plainland to the other side.

We are addressing a problem that is suboptimal to begin with, ergo solutions to the problem must also be.

Also, "Should" is futile where people simply *don't*. Adapting a system as much as reasonably possible to the way people are (or what people do) is a challenge that SO could aspire to for this particular problem. Users could be encouraged along the way to do things more "optimally."

Comment: Good point @PlasmaHH Post that as an answer and I'll upvote it...I promise!

Answer (score 22):

While a comment can often be the basis for a good answer, it will almost never make a good answer entirely as is.  Such comments should virtually always be modified to include more robust formatting, more complete information, more formal language, etc. while being converted to an answer.  When such comments are *just* copy/pasted into an answer they tend to make rather low quality answers.

On top of that, if you *do* just want to copy-paste the comment into an answer, it takes *very* little time; such a button isn't really saving anyone much effort at all.

Comment: I like this answer but it is missing one important criteria for me, I want the original commenter - who solved the problem to get some credit. Having a method to promote (give credit) and improve (better answer) works for everyone.

Comment: @Paxic If someone is using another user's comment as a basis for their answer they're obligated to cite them in order for it to not be plagiarism, so the author is going to be given credit for the work that is theirs.  If you see someone not crediting another's work, flag it accordingly.

Comment: "should" is a futile proposition where people simply *don't.*

Comment: @AlexHall What's your basis for that assertion?  In my experience people converting a comment into an answer almost always use it as a base and improve on it, and those that don't are virtually always received poorly by the community.

Comment: People avoid even the most teensy bit of extra work on computers. If I post links to my art on twitter, I get no clicks. If I post art inline, it gets attention. Here, folks can't be bothered to simply copy, paste and adapt a comment as an answer. I *mean*! That's *four* clicks and some typing! :) The great multitude of questions with valid answers in comments but no accepted answers proves this.

There could be a solution that reduces this to two clicks and typing. If that destabilizes merit, points could be adapted, for example users might get less points if their answer began as a comment.

Comment: @AlexHall If someone is just copy pasting a comment into an answer then they're almost certainly *posting a bad answer*, and we don't want to encourage that.  The hard part about making a comment a good answer isn't copy-pasting the comment to the answer box, it's adding all of the information that is necessary to complete the answer, which is why many comments aren't made into answers.

Answer (score 5):

While a comment can contain a solution, it isn't necessarily a good answer. It might require additional editing to be one, like providing additional information, links, or properly formed sentences.

If the commenter doesn't post an answer, you're free to do it yourself.

Posting an answer may also imply a form of responsibility of maintaining it. Perhaps the commenter does not want this responsibility.

Comment: Posting an answer also runs the risk of downvotes and lost reputation.  That risk doesn't exist with a comment.

Comment: It isn't necessarily *not* a good answer, either. I run across plenty of comments that are a perfect answer to a question.

Frankly, it is arbitrarily strict to avoid something merely because there is negative risk involved, where it is arguable that there can as easily be positive risk involved. It's a frankly negatively prejudiced view, where a realistic view is that answers in comments can be just as good or bad as outright answers.

Answer (score 2):

*Pulling my [answer from a duplicate question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328089/113632) here*

> I have posted a couple of Community Wiki answers that collected/summarized discussions in the comments that resolved the OP's issue. Even though it's not "my" answer I still put some time into curating the content so that it's better than comments on their own. To my knowledge this is a reasonable way to address answer-in-comments scenarios.

Regarding "*post that as an answer and I'll accept it*" comments specifically, I don't see anything wrong with them. Often times the commenter will take the time to expand on their comment so it's a high-quality answer (as they should). Automating the process would only serve to reduce the average answer quality in such cases.

Answer (score -5):

This could be based on several user votes, just like answer closings.  Its main value would be for old "*unanswered*" questions, where commentators are long gone.  But it shouldn't be entirely automatic, it could work like:

1. Comment flags should include a "promote comment to answer", where users vote a comment up.  The votes reduce the odds of bad code from being adopted by opportunists who just want points, and may not even understand the commentator's code.
2. Comment gets *n* user votes to promote.  Automatic new comment posted addressed to commentator, advising posting it as an answer.  They should have first dibs.
3. If and only if there's no answer by commentator -- suppose commentator is long gone, and 30 days passes, trigger *new*
   flag option "adapt comment to answer", with these features:

   - automatically posts introductory text crediting original commentator, and linking to comment.
   - adaptor gets credit, (or blame), for answer.  This should motivate better editing and formatting.

Comment: We can save all that trouble and immediately have the adaptor write an answer based on the comment in question.

Comment: @Justastudent, Reasons for "*that trouble*" given, see revised answer.