# Burninate: [answers-as-comments]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Just now, the [answers-as-comments](/questions/tagged/answers-as-comments) tag was added to a couple of (mostly old) questions.

Most of these questions are along the lines of *"X was posted as a comment, but should be an answer"*. These can (should) just be closed as duplicates:

- [Mark comments as answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271598/mark-comments-as-answers)
- [Duplicated comments in the form of answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267401/duplicated-comments-in-the-form-of-answers)
- [Add an option to 'promote comment to answer'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258343/add-an-option-to-promote-comment-to-answer)
- [Answerers who only use comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments)
- [What if a comment should be the (best) answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252482/what-if-a-comment-should-be-the-best-answer)
- [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)

That leaves one of them, about answers being "inspired" from comments, without giving credit:

- [Comment Poaching](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269913/comment-poaching)

I really don't see the added value of having this tag. [comment](/questions/tagged/comment) and [answer](/questions/tagged/answer) should be plenty.

So, what do you guys say? Burn it?

<sub>[Current questions with the tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/answers-as-comments?sort=newest)</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that it's only been added to 8 answers and just today, I'd say the simplest solution would be for someone (you?) to just roll-back those edits.

Also, if you think that they're duplicates, just vote to close.

Comment: I did on 2 unrelated questions already. Just wanted some more input before going on a tag demolition spree ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus - I don't think more input is needed if the tag has only just been created. If it was a long standing tag then maybe, but there's only a low number of questions involved anyway.

Comment: I removed the tags. The dupe-votes will have to wait 'till this evening :) Tags without questions get cleaned up automatically, right?