# What should I do when I see an answer posted as a comment?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

So recently I've noticed a slight tendency to post answers in comments, for whatever reason. It often really pisses me off. You have a perfectly valid answer but instead you are posting it as a comment, why? Actually, don't answer that, *it's irrelevant*.

So, back to the point. Today I snapped and [did this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281623/493122). It was a bad idea. I know, but it gave the message across, I guess.

So, what does the community think a user should do when he sees an answer in a comment? Should it copy but change it slightly (to prevent "plagiarism")? Does it really matter to change it slightly at that point? Should it """*take inspiration*""" from that?

Comment: I've answered plenty of questions in a comment because the question was trivial, I was going to vote to close, and/or I didn't care about getting any rep.  For example, someone has a typo in their code; I'll comment "You're missing a semi-colon on line 5", and vote to close as a typo, because the question is of no value to anyone else except the author.  If a comment as an answer pisses you off that much, maybe it's time to re-evaluate priorities.

Comment: If you're going to use a comment from another user as an answer, you should rightly cite it, whether you "take inspiration" from it or copy it verbatim. It's only right. It's more right the more you copy of it and the less of it is your own work. Now if you just use the basis of the comment to research the answer and flesh out your own, 100% complete answer, the citation might not be required... But giving credit for the pointer is still polite.

Comment: ITT: answers only on comments, to piss me off even more or because that's """clever""". Got it? I hate answers in comments, so there should be answers only on comments. That's so funny.

Comment: Lighten up, Francis

Comment: If you're going to use another person's work as your own you don't make superfluous changes to make it not be plagiarism, you cite it.  Making superfluous changes makes it still technically plagiarism, but just harder to prove.  Citing it makes it not actually be plagiarism.

Comment: see also questions listed in [Burninate: \[answers-as-comments\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271605/burninate-answers-as-comments)

Comment: You could post a Community Wiki answer, and credit the original author within that answer with a link to the comment and their profile.

Comment: @Doorknob冰 So wait, do I have to link to the profile too? Doesn't the comment already imply the user? Oh boi, this work is becoming tedious. I might just go back to not giving a crap. Seems less tiresome.

Comment: @Jefffrey See Jeff Atwood's post on [attribution](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) that is linked at the bottom of every page (in the part that says "user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required") for exactly what needs to be included in an attribution.

Comment: Just flag the original comment as "Obsolete".  One of the mods will instantly delete it, bam, problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to use a comment from another user as an answer, you should rightly cite it, whether you "take inspiration" from it or copy it verbatim. It's only right. It's more right the more you copy of it and the less of it is your own work. Now if you just use the basis of the comment to research the answer and flesh out your own, 100% complete answer, the citation might not be required... But giving credit for the pointer is still polite.

Comment: [(Stolen from Kendra)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281624/what-should-i-do-when-i-see-an-answer-posted-as-a-comment/281633#comment136552_281624)

Comment: @Martinho , wouldn't it be better to put the citation above... in the body?? and possibly in quotations ? rather than a comment? I just think it'd be nicer ;-)

Comment: But then it wouldn't be stolen! :P

Comment: Martinho - bah !  jokes jokes , smh

Comment: I had to downvote this but that's only part of the joke. +1 in hypothetical terms.

Comment: Oh.. are we only doing hypotheticals?   I'll take my real upvote back then.

Comment: How dare you! (I see what you did here. Nice. ;)

Answer (score 10):

There may be plenty of reasons a user choose not to answer.  It is possible they do not feel the comment is sufficient to address the question, it is possible they voted to close and do not believe in answering closed-worthy questions, it is possible the comment only addressed part of the question and they don't know the answer to the rest (or maybe it is a combination of all 3).

But if you feel a comment sufficiently answers the question, then it is fair game, but you need to be proper about it.

In my opinion there is a big difference between blatant plagiarism and using a comment as inspiration for an answer.
If you are going to take most of the content from a comment and provide it as your own answer without adding any original material, then the user who provided the original content must be cited.  You should treat this as you would any other professional writing.

If you take a comment for inspiration an provide your own answer complete with your own original work, then a citation is less necessary but is still better than not citing it at all.

Comment: It is also generally preferred that you mark the answer as a community wiki if it is not your own work (as in, copy-pasted). I've done this before myself in a similar situation, [removing an answer from the question body](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24561707).

Comment: Why cite someone that didn't consider it an answer? How is "plain plagiarism" any different than taking the comment and changing few words (or put in a better tone, again with 3 quotes: """take inspiration""" from it). At least by copying word by word you are being sincere.

Comment: @animuson It's a common convention, but it's certainly not required.  It's not wrong to post it as a traditional answer.  Of course, by doing so you're taking responsibility for the content's validity and quality.

Comment: @animuson I didn't know about that. Thanks. Then may I ask why didn't you remove the comment and made that a community wiki?

Comment: `Why cite someone that didn't consider it an answer?`  Are they your words?  No?  Then cite them.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Words are of nobody. They are simple words.

Comment: @Jefffrey You cite it because it's illegal to claim another person's intellectual property as your own.  It doesn't matter if it's an answer, a comment, or a scribble on the back of a napkin.  It's another person's property, not yours.

Comment: @Jefffrey - `Words are of nobody. They are simple words`.  Now you're either just trolling or being obtuse, I can't tell which.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I'm probably just stupid. Not everything that goes against your belief is "trolling".

Comment: @Jefffrey The individual words, yes, the ideas the can be combined to describe, no.

Comment: @Servy Then if you think your words are worth that much, get them copyrighted or something. Or defend them. I'm not taking the content from another answer, I'm taking the content from someone else's comment. Two completely different semantics.

Comment: @Jefffrey Copyright is implicit.  It is in fact there.  When the content is posted to SO it is also licensed under the CC-wiki, giving everyone in the world the right to distribute the content and created derived works from it, **so long as the content is appropriately cited when used**.  This all applies to comments just as much as answers.  The fact that you are *stealing* content from a comment, not an answer, doesn't make it any more okay.  As far as intellectual property rights are concerned, comments and answers are identical.

Comment: @Jefffrey RE your 2nd paragraph.... I doubt you really got any message across.  I am sure the author of the comment that inspired this post doesn't feel the comment was appropriate for a complete answer or he would have left it as an answer.

Comment: @psubsee2003 What if I do think the content is appropriate for a complete answer?

Comment: @Jefffrey then post it and cite it exactly as I said (especially if you are going to make an almost word-for-word copy.).  I am virtually certain that the author of that comment would approve :-)

Comment: @Jefffrey Then you can post it as one, **so long as you cite it appropriately**.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that this "answers as comments" nonsense is getting out of hand. Stack Overflow is not a chat room or forum or message board (indeed, its entire reason for being is to *not* be these things) and yet people are starting to treat it as such, ignoring the proper process for delivering answers to OPs.

There *are* some exceptions where it's okay, like when the question itself is a complete write-off and is never going to remain open or the solution was a stupid little typo and I'm going to get the question deleted thereafter as soon as possible.

I'd say that, in this case, the comment you stole was borderline. I honestly don't know whether I'd have posted it as a comment or an answer in this situation.

I certainly don't blame you for posting the same notion as an answer, but you should not have simply copy/pasted it word for word without any attribution whatsoever. Despite the fact that we do not accrue rep on meta, that sort of behaviour is simply dishonest, and violates the licence terms of the originally-posted content (so you're going to jail, sucka).

Comment: I had to upvote this.

Comment: There was a very specific reason I didn't make it an answer - I didn't want to make it searchable.  It exposed somewhat of a loophole that is known and you deserved to understand the mechanics, but I didn't want it to be easily found by anyone after that question falls off the front page

Comment: We need a "send OP to jail" flag option :D

Comment: @psubsee2003: Personally I think making something searchable or not searchable is the role of Stack Overflow and the way its developers decide to handle closed questions, _not_ something that we should attempt to achieve ourselves by "social engineering" and posting stuff in patently the wrong place. I appreciated the comment of course.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit on the whole, yes, I would agree.  But Meta is different.  Do we really need to to make "This is how you get your bounty to an unanswered question back" easier to find?

Answer (score 1):

I have to echo Servy's comment, we should not copy without attribution.

Although  I can see why you might be annoyed, I'm not sure there's anything at all we can do about it.

And plagiarism is not "plagiarism" , it is simply *plagiarism* which is well-defined and against our policy

Answer (score 0):

The proper thing to do is post the comment as a community wiki, giving attribution to the author.

Specifically, I'm paraphrasing [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281624/what-should-i-do-when-i-see-an-answer-posted-as-a-comment/281625?noredirect=1#comment136587_281624):

> You could post a Community Wiki answer, and credit the original author within that answer with a link to the comment and their profile.

Or maybe [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281624/what-should-i-do-when-i-see-an-answer-posted-as-a-comment/281625?noredirect=1#comment136561_281625):

> It is also generally preferred that you mark the answer as a community wiki if it is not your own work (as in, copy-pasted). I've done this before myself in a similar situation, removing an answer from the question body.

Or maybe [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281624/what-should-i-do-when-i-see-an-answer-posted-as-a-comment/281628#comment136586_281625):

> @Jefffrey Then you can post it as one, so long as you cite it appropriately.

What about [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281624/what-should-i-do-when-i-see-an-answer-posted-as-a-comment/281628#comment136569_281625)?

> @Jefffrey You cite it because it's illegal to claim another person's intellectual property as your own. It doesn't matter if it's an answer, a comment, or a scribble on the back of a napkin. It's another person's property, not yours.

I'm not sure.

Comment: Marking the post as CW is a convention that some people use, as it does indicate that the content is not your own.  It is not a requirement.  Citing the works however *is* a requirement, and marking the post as CW doesn't change that.

Comment: @Servy So, am I allowed to take reputation from someone else comment as long as I cite it?

Comment: You're allowed to post an answer that cite's another person's comment.  People are allowed to upvote that answer if they feel that it is helpful.  They're also allowed to downvote it if they feel that it's not helpful.  Can you potentially earn reputation by providing correctly cited content of another person, yes; will you necessarily earn reputation, no.