# Giving an answer that has been provided in comments

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

I've recently seen a couple of questions where people give suggestions for what could be a solution in the comments to a question. Then someone (Sometimes me, sometimes other users) comes in, realizes what the solution is based on the comment and posts that as an answer.

I feel like this is reasonable, since the users posting the comments to begin with could have posted it as an answer to begin with, since one can always delete (Or update) the answer if it proves to be wrong.

Is this accepted behavior? Or should I rather leave a comment saying that whoever commented first is probably right and encourage them to post it as an answer?

Comment: I would say it depends on the complexity. If it is a simple solution, go ahead and post the answer yourself-- the commenter likely doesn't care about the rep gain from answering and the question may be of limited future value. If it was a novel or clever solution you may not have thought of yourself, encourage the commenter to answer. See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272644/541091

Comment: But this has been discussed a few times before, and I'm looking for a suitable list of questions to link -- which is why I commented rather than answer ^^^

Comment: Unfortunately neither that nor the question this supposedly duplicates answers my question. I'm still wondering what the accepted practice is for dealing with this? Community Wiki was a good suggestion as mention in one answer but from my experience that's not what people actually do, not necessarily out of malice but simply because they don't know it exists.

Comment: @Rick There is no rule set in stone. Some people ping the comment author and suggest that they write an answer; others simply copy the comment to an answer after a certain amount of time has passed. Some people always make the answer a CW; others don't. Regardless of which approach you take, you must *always* cite the source properly. See [What should I do when I see an answer posted as a comment?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281624) for details.

Comment: @Rick FWIW, I try to follow common sense rules of etiquette when converting comments to answers. If I copy a comment verbatim and that is the only content in the answer (besides the attribution), I make it CW so it doesn't seem like I'm "profiting" from other users' contributions. If I copy a comment and then flesh it out further with my own words, code, etc., I might not make that CW since I put actual effort into creating that content. (I would still give attribution to the commenter, of course.) It's really up to you how you handle it, though.