# Should there be a "convert comment to answer"?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, answers, comments

Sometimes the answer is on a comment. Should there be a — obviously only accessible to the question poster — "Convert comment to answer" link/button? The new answer should appear as authored by the comment's poster, as it was he/she that contributed with a real solution to the problem being questioned.

I think it could contribute to diminish the number of unanswered questions wrongly assumed as so, as some of the questions are already answered in the comments and the phenomenon tends to grow.

The consequence is that potential helpers are losing their time entering in already answered questions and increasing the number of views to an amount the questions should not have.

Comments have also other disadvantages, as it is not obvious it is possible to make a reference to them directly (the timestamp is a link to them, but it is not intuitive to arrive to that conclusion) and formatting features are very much more limited.

Finally, comments are **less visible** than answers and the comment with top reputation does not come to the top. The consequence is it easier to see a lot of answers that do not for solving the problem than a comment that actually **has the resolution** on it.

I like the "Promote" idea on [Answerers who only use comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments#comment11206_253045)

Comment: *"it is not possible to make a reference to them directly"* - it is, clicking on the timestamp gives a link direct to a comment, like: `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328077/should-there-be-a-convert-comment-to-answer#comment367346_328077`.

Comment: I sometimes answer questions with a comment, usually because I don't have the time to write a proper answer or it might be because I think the question is off-topic and I've just close-voted it but I still want to help the person who asked. I would be very upset if such a comment was converted to an answer. If I had wanted to post it as an answer I would have done so. I (like to think I) understand the difference between comments and answers so at least for me it is a conscious decision I made when I chose to comment.

Comment: Worse, you can even answer a question by adding a tag.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Edited to improve truthfulness after your comment.

Comment: @GertArnold like adding [status-declined] to a [feature-request]?

Comment: Meanwhile it happened a thing: My own comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38411917/how-to-interact-mouse-click-with-control-list-in-vc-mfc-development#comment64232628_38411917 answers a question! I want to know about Stackoverflow's acceptable ethics of copy-pasting my comment to an an answer: Is it acceptable that another person, nor me, nor the asker, to do it? Is it acceptable for the asker to do it? If I do it on my own, does Stackoverflow flag me as some kind of Reputation digger and disable some of my account rights?

Comment: @sergiol People can copy your content and use it as they want (including posting it as an answer) as long as they provide proper attribution, that is as long as they mention that they got it from you.

Comment: If someone takes the time to clean up a comment I wrote and post it as an answer (remember, as Glorfindel mentioned we expect much more from an answer than we do from a comment) that's fine by me. If I wanted to do that I would have done it right away so I personally don't mind. And even if I did mind it wouldn't make a difference. By agreeing to SO's rules when signing up we both accepted that anything we post here can be used by others.

Comment: @ivarni if someone puts up a comment, any use of it is fair game. It is common to provide attribution, for many different reasons, but it is not a rule. This was according to Joe Wilson in the pub the other day.

Comment: 99.2% of "answers in the comment" that I see (or secretly make) are for questions which need to be closed. Allowing the OP to turn them into answers thinking that it was helpful would be a disaster.

Comment: @Glorfindel Obviously!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have posted a couple of Community Wiki answers that collected/summarized discussions in the comments that resolved the OP's issue. Even though it's not "my" answer I still put some time into curating the content so that it's better than comments on their own. To my knowledge this is a reasonable way to address answer-in-comments scenarios.

Answer (score 5):

From your original feature request, it was not clear who should be the owner of the new answer. If it is the OP of the question, he/she could just copy & paste the comment. This is hardly more work than clicking a 'convert to answer' link, and it also allows you to polish the contents a bit (e.g. newlines may help increasing readability, but they're not enabled in comments). As @dimo414 mentions, the OP can make a community wiki to make it easier for other users to expand, and/or if he/she feels he/she doesn't deserve the reputation that the answer may yield.

If it would be the *commenter*, that's **really** undesirable – a lot of things which are perfectly fine as a comment (e.g. *please try to foo the bar and see if it helps*) are awkward as an answer, and risk being flagged and/or downvoted. We just can't risk situations like these. In those case, just place another comment asking the commenter to convert the comment to an answer. This happens [quite](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315355/make-deleted-posts-searchable-for-30-days/315406#comment298614_315406) [often](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38247180/awk-not-printing-header-in-output-file#comment63916137_38247180).

Comment: I thought it was clear. Now I clarified, by a reasoning that seems the logical one.

Comment: Comments like "You missed a [specific obvious language element] at line [something to identify line]" are entirely useless as answers although, if given the power, the original querent might think them brilliances in the mire and worth making into an answer. Don't want that.