# Attribute answer to someone

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes, I want to make a comment in my question as an answer. I like to move that comment as answer myself and add some more description, if required. But, I like to attribute that answer to the person who made the comment. In that way, I give credit to the person who commented. Does it sound like a good feature?

Comment: What's stopping you from mentioning them in your answer?

Comment: I most often see people quoting the person, referring to them by [display] name, usually with a preceding `@` so readers know the cite is to another user on the site, and sometimes with a link back to the specific comment or the user’s profile or both. In extreme cases I see the answer marked as community wiki, in order to emphasize the collaborative nature of the answer (person who provided answer in comments and person who worked comment into an answer) and to eschew rep for someone else’s principal idea. But it would definitely be a **bad idea** to be able t post under someone else’s byline

Comment: If they wanted to post it as an answer, they would answer. As long as you say where you got your answer from (name of the user with a link to their profile), that is all that is needed. I don't think we would benefit from another system

Comment: I like to credit points to the person who commented. Any upvotes or mark as answered points should go to the person.

Comment: They won't get the points if you answer, even as a community wiki. There's no way to attribute people like that.

Comment: Just mention them in the answer. Why complicate the site with this? If you want them to have the reputation, then *ask them to create an answer*. If they then still don't post an answer, post our own and make your answer a community wiki post so you don't get rep for votes. Done.

Comment: @vijayst if they wanted points, they would have posted the answer as an answer.... i would prefer that someone cannot post an answer in my name, making me pingable... + what if whoever puts the answer in my name makes a mistake? I now have a wrong answer in my name? No.... or if I don't post an answer because I don't want to invest the time in crafting and then maintaining one? You can 'force' that on me now? Your feature opens up a lot of can of worms....

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Not a duplicate. This is a feature request; that is a discussion about said feature.

Comment: I don't really see a feature request...what is the proposed functionality?

Comment: If you have something to add to that, just write an answer and attribute the parts to the respective "owners". Also, make it owned by Community. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23578981/1312522

Comment: Very similar feature request - [promote comment to answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328077/should-there-be-a-convert-comment-to-answer) is already declined... Please make sure to address all concerns of that discussion in your feature request (at very least pushing responsibility for the answer including downvotes and maintenance to someone else).

Answer (score 3):

There's really no point to this feature. A person who posts a comment as an answer did so either:

1. Because they were unsure about whether it would actually answer the question. Perhaps the question is poorly phrased, or perhaps there are a half-dozen things wrong and they just picked one of them.
2. Because they don't actually want to post an answer. Perhaps they don't want to take the time to post a real answer with "some more description", or whatever.

> Any upvotes or mark as answered points should go to the person.

Answering through comments degrades the quality of the site. It leaves questions in an "unanswered" state. We should not reward such behavior by allowing such people to get rep for it due to the actions of someone else providing a real answer.

Furthermore, by adding "some more description", you're providing more value than the commenter. As such, you deserve those "points" more than the commenter.

If you want to credit a comment for your answer, then do so in the text of the answer. You can even link to the comment. But we need not provide anything beyond that.